# HTML5 Javascript: Save text onto canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, text, canvas

If you take a look at what I've done so far it'll help explain what I'm after, as I'm terrible at explaining normally haha. http://logomakr.bugs3.com/

On my drawing app I've implemented the ability to add text to the canvas, however, it's not recording/saving onto the canvas like the shapes are. When I've tried looking into it, it seems like HTML Canvas text tends to place over the canvas not on it.
I even copied a simple:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
```

to test it out, that displays on the canvas all fine and dandy but soon as you draw a shape it vanishes and even just pressing the save button the text isn't on the png?

Is there like an alternative or a way round it?

(Let me know if you need to see the code although I'm sure you's will be able to view source on website)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all try solving these two
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < www.serversfree.com:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Events is not defined logomakr.js:154

Comment: Ahh yeah that's a script the free server automatically adds. So if it was uploaded to normal server it might not say that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For drawn shapes (rects, circles, lines) you're using the mouseup event to trigger saving the "tempCanvas" to the "realCanvas".

But for text, you're not saving the tempCanvas to the realCanvas at all.  Then when you clear the tempCanvas for additional drawings, the text is blown away.  Maybe you could add a [save text] button so the user can trigger saving text's tempCanvas to realCanvas.

Comment: Ahright thank you for taking the time to explain, I shall try that thank you! :D

Comment: Thank you very much that worked a treat! Thank you for explaining what I had to do! :D